# Is it worth collecting jQuery-related scripts to run them at the end of the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I want to place jQuery just before the closing `</body>`-Tag like it's recommended. But because I'm using a Content Management System, inline scripts that require jQuery will be executed before the closing body tag.

My question now is: Is it worth to collect jQuery-based scripts in an array and run them at the end of the document when jQuery is loaded ([EXAMPLE](http://pastebin.com/1sAn08D8)) OR just load jQuery in the head section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could adopt the [approach described here](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/17/stop-paying-your-jquery-tax)

the idea is to create a `q` global variable soon in the header and use a temporary `window.$` function  to collect all the code/functions/plugin jQuery dependent.

```
window.q=[];
window.$=function(f){
  q.push(f);
};
```

and after you load jQuery you will pass all the functions to the real `$.ready` function.

```
$.each(q,function(index,f){
  $(f)
});
```

in this way you will be able to safely include your jquery code before the jQuery lib inclusion

If this could be better than loading jQuery in the head it may depends on how much code you have to push into `q` temporary function.

jQuery placed into `<head>` section would require a single blocking `script`. But if you have much code to inject everywhere inside the document you may have a lot of huge blocking scripts that stop the rendering process.

On the contrary loading a lot of scripts after dom ready event it could easily make your page faster to load so this approach it's better and the benefits can be more evident.

So there's no a definitive answer valid for all code and all pages: even if this kind of technique anyway is generally good and preferable (because you have the benefit of a as-later-as-possible script execution), you should **ever** make some test with both the approaches and look at loading and rendering time. *The article at the beginning has some consideration on the performance but also explains why stackoverflow didn't use it.*

Comment: Thank you. It's pretty similar to my approach though. But you haven't answered my question if it is worth it. I don't know if collecting and looping through the functions isn't even worse than loading jQ in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Just load jQuery in the head, it will be cached after the first load and won't slow down anything after that.

Everything else sounds like it would be over the top and I am not sure that the gain in performance will be that significant to justify the extra work.

Also sometime if your page load slowly with the javascript at the bottom it can take longer to come and load which means the visual without javascript might be visible and not provide such a good experience to the user.

Comment: We want visitors to see the visible content as soon as possible and putting jQuery in the head just delays that process.

Comment: So does everyone, yet if you look site like FB, Google, Youtube and others have JS in their head (not all as some loaded as needed of course). The performance get affected only once, then its cached, when script collection will have to run on every page load and thus affecting the performance of every pages. Sometime it's finding the right balance.

Comment: Big sites often use different optimisation techniques e.g. Google sticking masses of JS inline, that many web developers just aren't ready for - we're still too used to building sites in the way that's convenient for us rather than in a way that gives the visitor the best experience.  jQuery may be cached for the second page but the visitor still has to load the first page before they get to that and regardless of whether it's at the top or the bottom the JS still has to be executed on every page.  BTW req.js looks interesting - what made you decide to write your own loader?

Comment: Of course the original questioner has the problem of a CMS that wants to put JS inline - too many CMSs encourage bad practice.

Comment: @AndyDavies Optimization is an interesting topic :) req.js was mostly for fun and have some very basic tools to handle object as "module". I just like building tools which, to be honest, I don't generally use, I just enjoy the process.